# How can I fix a 403 "sorry you have exceeded your sharing quota" when using Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, http-status-code-403

This code is intended to iterate through a list of rows in a google sheet and perform the following logic:

- Check to see if folder exists under name "Course Workbooks - [First Name] - [User ID]
- If folder doesn't exist, create one under that name.
- Place copy of file in folder (new or existing)
- Give user and company email (john@example.com) editor access (the file is owned by the service account
- Update respective columns with "folder_id", "file_id", "updated_at" and "added". Added becomes "yes" when the user has been granted access so the program knows to skip over that row next time it is run.

I am running into two issues I need to solve:

- The code works as intended, although I consistently receive the following error (sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, although I need it to work consistently):

HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1HuUte9jdd4cvhb4mPLUifHLdBUR7-BgQ/permissions?alt=json returned "Rate limit exceeded. User message: "Sorry, you have exceeded your sharing quota."". Details: "[{'message': 'Rate limit exceeded. User message: "Sorry, you have exceeded your sharing quota."', 'domain': 'usageLimits', 'reason': 'sharingRateLimitExceeded'}]">

I think the issue has to do with that I am using 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' as my scope instead of 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', although when I change to the latter I get a 403 error and the script won't run at all.

- I get a similar error when I set john@example.com to be the owner of the file, which is more ideal than the service account being the owner of the file.

How am I able to get the correct authorization to both set john@example.com as the owner of the folder and run the script without getting a 403 error?

CODE HERE:

---

```
import os
import gspread
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import json
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# Google Sheets API details
SPREADSHEET_ID = "1i4E6V70CVo5cJY2vn1e3YeAmO80ZePt2lYFatlgy5SA"
WORKSHEET_NAME = "gdrive_database"

# Google Drive API details
DRIVE_API_VERSION = 'v3'

# Authenticate with Google Sheets API
scope_sheets = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
credentials_sheets = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/Users/kpi-updates-411718-82c6069f468f.json", scopes=scope_sheets)
credentials_sheets.refresh(Request())
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials_sheets)
worksheet = gc.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_ID).worksheet(WORKSHEET_NAME)

# Authenticate with Google Drive API
scope_drive = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials_drive = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/Users/kpi-updates-411718-82cd609f468f.json", scopes=scope_drive)
drive_service = build('drive', DRIVE_API_VERSION, credentials=credentials_drive)

for row in worksheet.get_all_records():
    start_row = 1
    cell_range_access = f'I{start_row + int(row["row"])}'
    credentials_drive.refresh(Request())
    if not worksheet.acell(cell_range_access).value:
        email = row['email']
        user_id = row['user_id']
        row_number = row['row']
        folder_name = f"Course Workbooks - {row['first_name']} - {user_id}"
        yes = "Yes"
        timestamp_now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        cell_range_file_id = f'G{start_row + int(row["row"])}'
        cell_range_folder_id = f'F{start_row + int(row["row"])}'
        cell_range_time = f'H{start_row + int(row["row"])}'
        cell_range_access = f'I{start_row + int(row["row"])}'

        # Check if folder exists
        folder_exists = False
        folders = drive_service.files().list(q=f"name='{folder_name}' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false").execute().get('files', [])
        if folders:
            folder_exists = True
            folder_id = folders[0]['id']
        else:
            # Create folder if it doesn't exist
            folder_metadata = {
                'name': folder_name,
                'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
                'parents': ['root']
            }
            folder = drive_service.files().create(body=folder_metadata, fields='id').execute()
            folder_id = folder['id']

            # Add ownership permission to the folder (service account)
            permission_metadata_owner = {
                'type': 'user',
                'role': 'owner',
                'emailAddress': 'kpi-updates@kpi-updates-411718.iam.gserviceaccount.com'  
            }
            drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=folder_id, body=permission_metadata_owner).execute()

        # Copy Test_file into the folder
        file_id_to_copy = "1iIKXMgJqySm__SUyP08x4GOAlvIXVdfBXzq_pA_DcLM"
        copy_metadata = {
            'parents': [folder_id]
        }
        copied_file = drive_service.files().copy(fileId=file_id_to_copy, body=copy_metadata).execute()
        copied_file_id = copied_file['id']

        # Add permission to the folder for the user
        permission_metadata_user = {
            'type': 'user',
            'role': 'writer',
            'emailAddress': email
        }
        drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=folder_id, body=permission_metadata_user).execute()

        # Add permission to the folder for the admin
        permission_metadata_admin = {
            'type': 'user',
            'role': 'writer',
            'emailAddress': 'john@example.com'
        }
        drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=folder_id, body=permission_metadata_admin).execute()

       # update values

        worksheet.update_acell(cell_range_file_id, copied_file_id)
        worksheet.update_acell(cell_range_folder_id, folder_id)
        worksheet.update_acell(cell_range_time, timestamp_now)
        worksheet.update_acell(cell_range_access, yes)

            # Print feedback
        print(f"Row {row['row']}: {'Folder created' if not folder_exists else 'Folder already existed'}, Folder ID: {folder_id}, Document ID: {copied_file_id}")
    else:
        print(f"Skipping row {row['row']} as column 'I' is not empty.")
```

Additional Context: The database has the following columns (in order): row  first_name  last_name   email   user_id   folder_id file_id   updated_at    access

I tried the following code above and resulted in a 403 error

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google+drive+%22Rate+limit+exceeded%22. Just wondering, do you understand what that error means? In any case, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].